# Сортировка массива без использования стандартных методов

Tags: массивы, javascript, сортировка

Как можно отсортировать массив не прибегая к стандартному методу [JS Array Sort](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp)?

Comment: самостоятельно реализовать любой понравившийся  [алгоритм сортировки][1] 


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8#.D0.A1.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BA_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8

Comment: Можно, вот пример [Quicksort](https://gist.github.com/paullewis/1981455). P.S. Только зачем? **UPD**: Ох, совсем забыл — http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: @DreamChild бережнее к новичкам - бережнее...

Comment: Иногда, на такие вопросы хочется ответить просто превратив вопрос ответ. :-) в данном случае, как : как отсортировать не использовав стандартную вещь - отсортировать самому, реализовав один из алгоритмов предложенных при поиске в интернете.

Вообще беда на форуме с темами, люди сами не знают что хотят спросить.

Comment: Холивар про темы не начинайте, так, лишу взболтнул.

Comment: Вообще-то Array.sort() может принимать один аргумент, который и будет функцией, реализующей сортировку и возвращающей отсортированный массив. Так же готовые реализации некоторых алгоритмов сортировок есть здесь http://www.nczonline.net/blog/tag/sorting/

Comment: @Lucky не функцию сравнения ?

Comment: @eicto, нет. Все таки функцию сортировки

Comment: @Lucky [да](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8zduH/) ? [compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [comparefn](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) ничего не говорит ?

Comment: @eicto, да. согласен. В каком-то смысле это функция сравнения. Но в общем ведь происходит сортировка массива с помощью этой функции.

Comment: @Lucky Не "в каком-то смысле", а в прямом - это функция сравнения элементов , к алгоритму сортировки она отношения не имеет.

Comment: @eicto, вот тут я не согласен. Почитайте вот это http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_сортировки , раздел Свойства и классификация. И вот это Вам не о чем не говорит http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/4b4fbfhk(v=vs.94).aspx ?

Comment: реализуйте "пузырёк" с помощью этой функции ага. в спецификации написано comparefn, о чем вы спорите ? В wiki * Алгоритмы, использующие для сортировки сравнение элементов между собой, называются основанными на сравнениях. * вы об этом ? так это просто говорит, что в движках js которые соответствуют ecmascript 5.1 (наверное и более ранним - не смотрел) Array.prototype.sort всегда реализует **основанными на сравнениях алгоритм** .

Answer (score 2):

Я предлагаю простенький алгоритм "Пузырька".

Делаешь 2 цикла (один вложен), в первом перебираешь записи **i = от 1 до N-1** во втором **j = от i+1 до N**. Дальше сравниваешь внутри циклов i-ый элемент и j-ый, если больше, то меняешь элементы местами.

*На мой взгляд это тот метод сортировки, который должен быть изучен в первую очередь*.

Comment: Он и изучается в первую очередь.

Comment: а мне больше сортировка выбором нравится...